# swift 3 set date picker current date and calculate difference

Tags: macos, date, cocoa, swift3

(Swift 3, OSX)

i would like to set the date picker current date as the actual date - but i don't know how.

and i would like to get the difference between the selected date and the actual date. for this i use this code but i get sometimes a wrong value:

```
@IBAction func DatePickerChange(_ sender: NSDatePicker) {

   let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: NSDate() as Date, to: datePicker.dateValue)
   print(difference.day!+1)
}
```

Comment: *"but i get sometimes a wrong value"* - aha... wrong in what way? What is the input, what is the actual and desired output?

Comment: if I select the actual date in date picker, the output is: `month: 0 day: 0 hour: 0 minute: 0 second: -1 isLeapMonth: false` = 0 day difference = ok, but if i select one day later as the actual date the output is: `month: 0 day: 0 hour: 23 minute: 58 second: 37 isLeapMonth: false`= 0 day difference => have to be 1 day

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to set current date -

```
yourDatePicker.setDate(Date(), false)
```

to get the difference in days -

```
Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: yourDatePicker.date, to: self).day
```

Comment: i found the solution for the actual date as default: `datePicker.minDate = NSDate() as Date`

Comment: That is not actual date, that is minimum possible value for you datePicker. If you need to choose date before current date, you will not be able to do so. You should use `datePicker.setDate(Date(), animatedValue)`, NSDate is from Objective C, in Swift 3 you may use Date.

Comment: setDate is not available: `Value of type 'NSDatePicker' has no member 'setDate'`

Comment: okay i found the solution for setting the default date: `datePicker.dateValue = Date()`